# Dynamic range in excel: How to remove Counta counting blank cells(made blank by ifferror formulas)

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have to plot a data in chart which I have made dynamic by using a named range using offset, counta(for required rows) in the chart area.

The problem with using counta is it counts the rows which has blank cells(made blank by iferror formula),which I do not want.Moreover I cannot remove those formulas 'coz when the data is there that has to be dynamically present in the chart.

```
OFFSET('ABC'!$T$2,1,0,COUNTA('ABC'!$T2:$T1000),4)
```

Here; let us say the values are there for 10 rows;but the formulas are till 15 so how do I stop counta from counting the 5 rows(which have been made blank by iferror).

Answer (score 1):

To remove the blank cells from the count you can use the `COUNTBLANK` function of Excel.

Simply subtract the value of `COUNTBLANK` from the result of `COUNTA`

Example:

`=COUNTA(yourRange)-COUNTBLANK(yourRange)`